# Whats wrong with my Mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, terminal, vi, hybrid-mobile-app, bash

I've recently set a path in my vi .bash_profile to my mongo commands. I know this works because it was working yesterday.

**However when I do it now I get this error:**

```
AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ james.flan$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: test
2015-05-19T11:34:58.708+0100 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2015-05-19T11:34:58.710+0100 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed
```

**Here is the content in my vi .bash_profile:**

```
alias mongod="mongod --dbpath /Users/ryan.garrett/Documents/Software/MongoDB/data"
export PATH="/Users/ryan.garrett/Documents/Software/MongoDB/bin:$PATH"
```

Can someone please tell me how to connect to the server?

Comment: Think you db server is not startet or is not listening on port 27017 on localhost

Comment: I go into my app and I do and 'npm start' which just gets errors

Comment: Also, check that you did not activate security (auth=true in config file) before creating a DB admin.

Comment: What do you see when you run `ps -ef | grep mongod`?

Comment: AMAC02MX3APF8J3:~ ryan.garrett$ ps -ef | grep mongod
1506864737  4888  4879   0  2:25pm ttys000    0:00.00 grep mongod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your /etc/hosts for localhost entry and also make sure that mongod is listening to all interfaces, you can check by netstat -an|grep mongo.